# Ubuntu Login Screen goes black on Ubuntu 16.04, Cuda 8.0 and Geforce GTX Titan X GPU

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda, nvidia-geforce, gpu-driver

I have a Geforce GTX Titan X GPU machine. When it was 15.10, CUDA 7.5 and NVIDIA display driver 352.63 things were fine. Recently I wanted to install caffe2  that requires a CUDA 8.0. So I upgraded Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 as CUDA 8.0 is available for 16.04. I installed CUDA 8.0 and the default display driver comes with it as well. After installation, the screen had gone black. Later installed CUDA 9.0 and the result was the same. Keeping CUDA 9.0, I installed various NVIDIA drivers from 361 to 375 to 384 to the recent 390. Nothing worked for me. I followed blacklisting nouveau, 'nomodeset' in grub, completely removing the older NVIDIA drivers and so on. But I couldn't able to figure out a solution to overcome the problem. Can anyone help me to figure out a solution given the above specification?. Please note that I followed all other Stack Exchange solutions for a black screen/log in problems however the GPU and Ubuntu version are different and those solutions didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Install fresh Ubuntu OS (16.04). Check if you have a NVIDIA graphics card

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

2)Run the following commands in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install  build-essential
sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

3)Add the repository containing nvidia latest drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

4)Open System Settings > Softwares & Updates > Additional Drivers. Select the latest nvidia-driver that you can see instead of the nouveau driver that is selected by default. Click on apply changes and wait for the process to finish
(Or)

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

5)Reboot
Verify the nvidia driver is selected in the above Additional Drivers location 
(or) run the following and check if driver is nvidia

```
sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration
```

6)Run the following command to create the file

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

In the editor add the following lines:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

7)Run the following command

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

8) Download Cuda runfile installer from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
    This currently has cuda 9.1. Older versions are also available in the site.
9)Reboot
10)Run the following commands

```
sudo chmod 755 <Path-to-cuda-runfile>
sudo sh <Path-to-cuda-runfile>
```

The installer will prompt for the following:
    EULA Acceptance - accept
   *CUDA driver installation - no (Important that you do not install driver here)
    Install CUDA toolkit - yes at default path
    Create Symbolic link - yes
    Install CUDA samples - yes at default path
11)Reboot and login
12)Edit the ~/.bashrc file and add the following at the end

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${CUDA_HOME}/lib64
export PATH=$PATH:${CUDA_HOME}/bin
```

13)Open a new terminal and run the following command to verify nvcc compiler

```
nvcc --version
```

OPTIONAL - Build and test cuda samples
14) Run the following

```
cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA_*_Samples
make 
cd 1_Utilities/deviceQuery
sudo ./deviceQuery
```

The above app should output PASS